# ZF2 Profiler Firebug is not available?

Tags: zend-framework2

ZF1 has Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug for logging db queries. It very very useful! 
Is there something like that in ZF2?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [BjyProfiler module](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyProfiler), he has made a port of the ZF1 profilers.